# Issue in rollback in Doctrine Migrations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-migrations

Im using Symfony 2.3.1 and I want to deploy my database with DoctrineMigratios but I'm having some troubles on the "up()" function.
If I try to execute this example:

```
$this->addSql("CREATE TABLE User (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL");
$this->addSql("CREATE TABLE User (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL");
```

I have an error (of course, is the same table) but DoctrineMigrations doesn't execute the rollback and finally I have the "User" table in my database.
Don't know if is a problem of my configuration or project, or maybe is a bug of DoctrineMigrations.

Somebody could help me, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think problem is not in doctrine. If you are using MySQL as RDBMS please read about implicit commit [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/implicit-commit.html):

> The CREATE TABLE statement in InnoDB is processed as a single transaction. This means that a ROLLBACK from the user does not undo CREATE TABLE statements the user made during that transaction.